# How does this function which reverses the interleave process into x number of subsequences

Tags: clojure

I completed [exercise 43](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/43) on 4clojure the other day and checked some of the other solutions. One in particular has confused me.

The challenge asks you to write a function which satisfies all of these:

```
(= (__ [1 2 3 4 5 6] 2) '((1 3 5) (2 4 6)))
(= (__ (range 9) 3) '((0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8)))
(= (__ (range 10) 5) '((0 5) (1 6) (2 7) (3 8) (4 9)))
```

My solution was this:

```
(fn [l n] 
    (map #(map second %) (vals (group-by #(mod (first %) n) 
    (map vector (iterate inc 0) l)))))
```

User [*himself*](http://www.4clojure.com/user/himself) had this solution:
    `#(apply map list (partition %2 %1))`
and I couldn't work out how it worked.

Let's work through the first problem:

```
(= (__ [1 2 3 4 5 6] 2) '((1 3 5) (2 4 6)))
```

well the `(#(partition %2 %1) [1 2 3 4 5 6] 2)` would give us `((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))` now how does `apply map list` on that produce `(1 3 5) (2 4 6)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[apply](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) is using the `((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))` as a variable length list of additional arguments. Then iteration of the map is applying the `list` function to all three of these additional lists.

As a result it expands as follows:

```
   (apply map list '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
=> (map list '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
=> (list 1 3 5) and (list 2 4 6)
```

Comment: In case it is not obvious why `map` would do this (it wasn't to me), when you pass in more than one collection `map` will apply f to
the set of _first_ items of each collection, followed by applying f to the
set of _second_ items in each collection. I was used to seeing a single collection passed to `map` and I didn't expect this when it was passed more than one.